# Resize image before using in imagecopymerge

Tags: php, file-upload, resize

I have a prorgam that uses imagecopymerge.  Here, I'm using two images.  First image for background and second one to be placed inside it.  I am able to do so, but now I want the second image to be on a certain size. this image is uploaded by user and saved at my server so i dont have control on it's size. How can I resize the second image before using it in my imagecopymerge?  Thanks a lot for answering.  Please also consider that resizing it during upload is my least option. I want the size to be 255x175.

This is what I have:

```
$uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name'])

$upload = $uploadFilename;
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("bg.jpg");
$img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$font = 'arialbi.ttf';
$font2 = 'ariali.ttf';

$newtitle = wordwrap($title, 28, "\n", true);
$newertitle = explode("\n", $newtitle);

imagettftext($im, 28, 0, 7, 270, $black, $font, $newertitle[0]);
imagettftext($im, 28, 0, 7, 320, $black, $font, $newertitle[1]);
imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 320, 362, $black, $font, $namehere);

imagecopymerge($im, $img2, 10, 350, 0, 0, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2), 100);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Use `imagecopyresampled()` on the image you wish to resize, infact you could use this to perform your "merge" operation as it has source/destination widths and heights

Comment: @Scuzzy thans for answering. can you give me some code? so i would know how. thank for helping me further

Comment: [imagecopyresampled()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) is so similar to [imagecopymerge()](http://us3.php.net/imagecopymerge) you really shouldn't have a problem implementing it yourself, just pay close attention to the parameter order as the 7th parameter onwards is different.

Comment: can you give me a sample code? i have read php.netmanual and im abit confused. thank you

Comment: and it also uses percentage. i want to come up wuth the size 255x175px, how can u come up with this if it's using percentage? thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Take your code...

```
imagecopymerge($im, $img2, 10, 350, 0, 0, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2), 100);
```

And change it to...

```
imagecopyresampled($im, $img2, 10, 350, 0, 0, 255, 175, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2));
```

Comment: i have tried it but i only want the $img2 to be resized. not the whole image.

Comment: please help me i also end up in with this code and situation befroe i post this quetion. i'm really losing hope.

Comment: or is it possible if i imagecopyresampled the $img2 and then when its resized i can use it in my imgcopymerge? please refer to the code in my question. the $img2 is the uploaded file. imentioned it there. thanks

Comment: here is the description from the imagecopyresampled page of the PHP website... **imagecopyresampled() copies a rectangular portion of one image to another image, smoothly interpolating pixel values so that, in particular, reducing the size of an image still retains a great deal of clarity.**

this is exactly what you want to do right? Please upload sample graphics somewhere for me to test with.

Comment: I've tested exactly what I've provided to you and it works as expected (except I change 10,350 to 10,35 to put the graphic up the top... http://i.imgur.com/SfGDLTK.jpg

Comment: yes its working now! worked like a charm! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use [php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php)
given as:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("source_of_img.jpg");
$imgresize = imagescale($dp,200,200);
```